# A question based on polynomials and relation between roots

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

[image]

I tried a few relation between roots and coefficients but I am not able to solve this question.

Comment: Have you tried vieta’s formulas?

Comment: notice that $\alpha^{-3} = 1/(9\alpha - 9)$ and similarly for the others. Then apply Vieta

Comment: It can be annoying, but every symmetric polynomial can be expressed as elementary symmetric polynomial, look up some proof of this, usually it also gives a algorithm(for instance Procesi Lie Groups chapter 2 or Jacobson Basic Algebra vol 1 chapter 2 on rings)

Comment: thanks @razivo....I used vieta's relations.

Comment: thanks @Exodd.... I applied vieta's relations but getiing answer to second part as 4/9 but answer given is 4....could you cross check.

Comment: @harshuljain Yeah, I also get 4/9

Comment: @Exodd Thanks a lot for clarifying!!